# Magento cart is always empty on chrome and opera

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, html, cookie

After i add some products to card and i open cart page it shows "the cart is empty". it just happens in chrome and opera; but every thing is ok in firefox.
i have checked cookie management and every thing was fine there. what is the problem?
*my magento is running on local server.

Comment: Refer this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92886/cant-log-into-secure-ssl-magento-site-on-front-end-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a cookie or session issue. It's hard to say with out more info so here are a few suggestions to start debugging:

- Use the chrome developer tools and inspect your cookies. There should be a cookie named "frontend" with a value of jumbled letters / numbers.
- Check your session storage (`var/session/`) for a file named `sess_XXXXXXX` where XXXXXXX matches the value for the `frontend` cookie.

If those 2 things exist, it should work.

Comment: var/session/ is empty.
im using magento on local.

Comment: have you given 777 permission to var/ folder ? if don't then give it.

Comment: Check your app/etc/local.xml file. There should be a part that indicates where your session files should be stored whether that be files, database, memcache, etc. If not already set to files try changing it to files. Easier to debug. The code looks like this: `<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`