# Frontend Cannot login after SSL installed

Tags: magento-1.9, login, ssl

We installed SSL and got the https:// working on our magento 1.9.2 site however we can only login once when we clear our cookies. We can not logout and then log back in again...When we press login it just goes back to the same login page again...unless we clear our cookies and reset the browser.   We tried adding the form_key after  to both the customer and peristent login files but its still not working. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: see here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93406/21339

Answer (score 0):

try this code frinds:-
Magento 1.9 has been used form key validation at customer loggin and register page.On Post action it check the form key using function `_validateFormKey()` at controller

form key  issue: form key missing so add this code in your form

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

OR

**Cookie domain setting issue goto check setting** is proper or not

at **Admin>System>configuration>General>Web>Session Cookie Management**

Comment: Hello we have tried the formkey solution. Is our Session Cookie Management setting correct?